# How to set dynamic default email message in DocuSign

Tags: docusign

How would setup dynamic default email message in docuSign, I want to control the message through Custom Labels.

[Screen shot pic:](https://nickahn.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/docusign.png)

I have the following code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//

var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';

//*************************************************//

//Toggle load attachments

LA = '0'; // 0 = off, 1 = on

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;

//*******************************************//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DocuSign for Salesforce Administrator's Guide](https://support.docusign.com/guides/docusign-for-salesforce-administrator-guide) is where you should look.

Therein, in the section "Custom Button Configuration", you'll find a list (and explanations) of all of the parameters that you can pass to DocuSign.

Setting the `CEM` parameter should accomplish what you're looking to do.

From the documenation I linked:

> CEM
>
> A text string with the email message.
>
> The message text string supports the use of custom tags, such as:
>   [FirstName] = sender first name, [LastName] = sender last name,
>   and [Email] = sender email.
>
> The text string also supports Salesforce
>   merge fields.
>
> Example: CEM='Envelope sent by [FirstName] [LastName] ([Email])
>   for {!Opportunity.Name}';
>
> - The text string is limited to 2000 characters. Anything beyond 2000
>     characters is truncated in the email message.
> - If no value supplied, the default email message is used.
> - The default message is set in DocuSign Admin, Envelopes, as described in
>     Changing Email Settings.
> - Fields that are text strings must not contain either ‘,’ (comma) or ‘;’
>     (semicolon), because those two characters are used to parse the
>     string.
> - Commas and semicolons could be used in the RecipientNote, so you can specify *COMMA* or *SEMI* to embed a ‘,’ or ‘;’ in the note. You can use ‘\n’ to embed a carriage return in the note.
>
> Example: If RecipientNote~RecipientNote__c is:
>   “Hi_COMMA_\nThis is a wonderful opportunity_SEMI_ please
>   sign.\nThank you.”
>
> The note appears as:
>
> Hi,
>
> This is a wonderful opportunity; please sign.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: 1+Thanks Derek for pointing out the pdf.

Comment: do you able to get the line break working? my docusign did not set the line break and showing the literal string \n in the Email Body. Also the documentation link is dead